# Application bloat by using third parties library in NPM & Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a project with a friend.

He is by far a better programmer than I am, as I have been programming for a little over a year.

I noticed he often builds components, and functionality from scratch. I'd consider him almost a "hipster" in terms of building functionality from scratch.

Is there any downside to my approach of utilizing npm libraries, etc for use? Ie. Date Pickers, Map Components, etc?

One reason I might conjure up is that perhaps there's a performance hit. Will load time be affected significantly? I'm not building a large application, in fact I'd consider it small, BUT! I'm wondering if I'm "cheating", OR this will lead to bloat.

As a quick preview, my basic functionality would currently look to include:

- Emoji Picker
- Date Picker
- Google Maps API Maps Component & Places
- Form Validation Library
- Superagent
- Moment.js

Comment: This question might be "too broad" for SO - but to give you my 2c. It's situational. If a library is well maintained, it's probably going to be coded better than something you can put together yourself in a few hours. However, if you aren't leveraging the full utility of the library, you will likely be wasting space in your bundle. For example - if you are importing ALL the locales from Moment.js and using 2 of them, that is bad.

Comment: (ctd) Don't be afraid to use libraries if they will save you time, but be aware of the size you are adding to your final bundle and make a decision based on time saved vs performance. There are various tools you can use to analyze the space each dependency is taking up.

Comment: Your friend has "Not Invented Here Syndrome."   It's certainly possible to overuse external libraries; it's good to ensure you're not pulling in redundant functionality or pulling in an entire library just to use one small part of it. But in general library code will be more battle-tested and hardened than your own, simply because more people have used it.

Comment: (I concur that this question is likely to be closed as "primarily opinion based" but I couldn't resist putting my opinion in)

Comment: No! Thank you guys very much! (I did take a look around, and noticed there wasn't any similar questions, but I do think it  might be useful for other programmers). The insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're not cheating.
It's quite common for developers to use third party packages.
But it can be good experience learning to build your own components.
Don't forget you can always swap them out as your experience, knowledge grows

Pros.

- They can save you development time.
- They can do things that you may find difficult to implement.
- They can be better written and tested.

Cons.

- They can be badly written, unreliable, unsupported.
- If you don't know how they work they can be problematic if there's a bug or if you need to extend the functionality.
- You could end up including a lot of script that is unused.
- You might be able to write something better and more maintainable.

Bundling, minifying, uglifying your JavaScript and tree shaking with  tools like rollup can help keep your download sizes down.

If you use packages, use reliable ones, look at reviews and ratings, check out the activity and issues log.

As with all concerns performance related - test.
Use fiddler or chrome to see how big your downloads are, measure your download times.
Where possible test under realistic device/network/load conditions.

Comment: Great! I'll look up more targeted information on how to keep my bundle size down: "Bundling, minifying, uglifying your JavaScript and tree shaking with tools like rollup can help keep your download sizes down."

Answer (score 0):

It's a good test of knowledge on your part, since you are new, to attempt to write all of those things yourselves. It's how a good portion of the users of stackoverflow learned: take on a project that sounds doable, but has an unknown section for you at the time. It's how I personally learned just about everything I know.

That being said, I don't think it's cheating. There's a common phrase in English: "Don't reinvent the wheel." The reason that those libraries exist is because someone took a lot of time to make them, and then realized that other people could probably benefit from it as well. With the example of Moment, working with Date/Time in any language is a huge pain, and the reason Moment is so popular is because no one wants to go through all of what Moment's creator(s) went through already. Why waste time reinventing a perfectly good, well tested, and reliable wheel?

Now if ever you go "man, this wheel is nice, but wouldn't it be better if they were made out of something more durable so that they can go over more bumps?" then in this case you are improving the wheel -- and similarly there are many projects that started off as a fork from an already existing one looking to add what the author felt was missing functionality.